# VHDL: I can port map std_logic_vector to a signed or unsigned port, why?

Tags: vhdl

VHDL is type-safe, thus how is it that I am able to use a std_logic_vector signal and port map it to a entity port that is of type signed?

Shouldn't it require some sort of "qualification" or "casting"?

Comment: What kind of tool are you using? In Vivado, it is marked as an error: "[Synth 8-2778] type error near input ; expected type signed"...

Comment: As @gstorto asks, what software tool is letting you do this?

Answer (score 5):

You can use a type conversion in an association list e.g. in a port map.

Depending on the (port) direction, you need to specify the conversion either on the formal (*out*put), actual (*in*put) or both sides (inout).

```
port map (
  myUnsigned                  => unsigned(mySLV1),  -- input  (in)
  std_logic_vector(mySigned1) => mySLV2,            -- output (out)
  std_logic_vector(mySigned2) => signed(mySLV3)     -- bidirectional (inout)
);
```

Answer (score 1):

It is actually not allowed:

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;

-- ============================================================================ --
-- Entity declaration                                                           --
-- ============================================================================ --
entity first is
    port
    (
        input  : in  std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
        output : out std_logic_vector(7 downto 0)
    );
end entity first;

architecture rtl of first is
-- ============================================================================ --
-- Signal declaration                                                           --
-- ============================================================================ --

-- ============================================================================ --
-- Code starts                                                                  --
-- ============================================================================ --
begin
  second_inst : entity work.second
    port map (
      input => input,
      output => output
    );
end architecture rtl;
```

#

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;

-- ============================================================================ --
-- Entity declaration                                                           --
-- ============================================================================ --
entity second is
    port
    (
        input  : in  signed(7 downto 0);
        output : out signed(7 downto 0)
    );
end entity second;

architecture rtl of second is
-- ============================================================================ --
-- Signal declaration                                                           --
-- ============================================================================ --

-- ============================================================================ --
-- Code starts                                                                  --
-- ============================================================================ --
begin
  output <= input;
end architecture rtl;
```

The error is detected by Vivado, and I am pretty sure the same should happen with Quartus:

```
ERROR: [Synth 8-2778] type error near input ; expected type signed [first.vhd:27]
ERROR: [Synth 8-2778] type error near output ; expected type signed [first.vhd:28]
```

Comment: It's possible. As the OP asked, a type cast - VHDL calls it type conversion - is required.

Comment: @Paebbels If you are type casting to unsigned/signed, you are not filling a std_logic_vector to the submodule. It is the same thing as saying that when you are casting a std_logic_vector to unsigned and applying an increment, you are doing arithmetical operations with a std_logic_vector, which is not true.

Comment: The reason for your errors is that the two ports named inputs have different base types. One has a base type of std_ulogic_vector, the other unresolved_sign (or signed for pre -2008).  std_logic_vector and signed can undergo explicit *type conversion* to the other because they have the closely related element types (both have an element base type of std_ulogic) and dimensionality.